# Find the general solution to this a equation.

Tags: trigonometry

> Find the general solution of $$ 2 \sin (4πx)+\sqrt{3}=0 $$

I am aware of how to find the general solution of a normal trigonometric equation, but it's just that this problem has a negative solution on the right hand side ($\frac{-\sqrt{3}}{2}$) So when I try to solve for the solution, I'm not really sure which angle to use for $\sin^{-1} \frac{-\sqrt{3}}{2} $ . Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: If $\sin\theta \lt 0$, you know that you can only be in 2 quadrants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

$$\sin\dfrac{4\pi}{3}=\sin\dfrac{5\pi}{3}=-\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}.$$

Comment: Thank you very much, I thought I tried this before but clearly not.. :)